# AWS S3: How to generate a signature for Put Object Copy with ColdFusion?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, coldfusion

I am trying to use the put Object copy functionality of s3 (s3 replaces the file) with user defined metadata in ColdFusion. I am using Joe Danziger's functions (https://gist.github.com/CFJSGeek/3f6f14ba86049af75361) to create the signature.
However I keep getting the error that my signature does not match. Any ideas? **Here's my code:**

```
public function setMetaDataForObject(string bucket, string objectKey, struct metadata){
    var dateTimeString = GetHTTPTimeString(now());
    writedump(metadata);
    var cs = "PUT\n\nimg/png\n#dateTimeString#\nx-amz-copy-source:/#arguments.bucket#/#arguments.objectKey#\nx-amz-metadata-directive:REPLACE\n";
    for(key in arguments.metadata){
            cs &= "#key#:#metadata[key]#\n";                
        }           
    cs &= "/#arguments.bucket#/#arguments.objectKey#";
    writeoutput(cs);
    var signature = createSignature(cs);
    var httpReq = new http();
        httpReq.setMethod("PUT");
        httpReq.setUrl("http://#arguments.bucket#.s3.amazonaws.com/#arguments.objectKey#" );
        //httpReq.setTimeout(timeout="300");
        httpReq.addParam(type="header", name="Date", value="#dateTimeString#");
        httpReq.addParam(type="header", name="Content-Type", value="img/png");
        httpReq.addParam(type="header", name="x-amz-copy-source", value="/#arguments.bucket#/#arguments.objectKey#");
        httpReq.addParam(type="header", name="x-amz-metadata-directive", value="REPLACE");
        httpReq.addParam(type="header", name="Authorization", value="AWS #variables.accessKeyId#:#signature#");
        for(var i in arguments.metadata){
            httpReq.addParam(type="header", name="#i#", value="#arguments.metadata[i]#");
        }

        //httpReq.addParam(type="body", value="#fileS3#");
        var result = httpReq.send().getPrefix(); writedump(result); 
}
```

**Joe Danziger's code (that i rewrote in script):**

```
private binary function HMAC_SHA1(required string signKey, required string signMessage){
    var jMsg = JavaCast("string",arguments.signMessage).getBytes("iso-8859-1");
    var jKey = JavaCast("string",arguments.signKey).getBytes("iso-8859-1");
    var key = createObject("java","javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec");
    var mac = createObject("java","javax.crypto.Mac");

    key = key.init(jKey,"HmacSHA1");
    mac = mac.getInstance(key.getAlgorithm());
    mac.init(key);
    mac.update(jMsg);

    return mac.doFinal();
}

private string function createSignature(required string stringIn){
    var fixedData = replace(arguments.stringIn,"\n","#chr(10)#","all");
    var digest = HMAC_SHA1(variables.awsSecretKey, fixedData);
    var signature = ToBase64("#digest#");
    return signature;       
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I solved this problem:
the headers need to be sorted alphabetically!
(when being passed in to the createSignature function.. it doesn't seem to be giving a problem with the actual http headers)
here's my updated code:

```
public function setMetaDataForObject(required string bucket, required string objectKey, struct metadata, string contentType){

    if(!isdefined("argumetns.contentType")){
        var meta = getMetaDataForObject(arguments.bucket, arguments.objectKey);
        arguments.contentType = meta['Content-type'];
    }

    var dateTimeString = GetHTTPTimeString(now());
    var cs = "PUT\n\n#arguments.contentType#\n#dateTimeString#\nx-amz-copy-source:/#arguments.bucket#/#arguments.objectKey#\n";
    if(isdefined("arguments.metadata")){
        for(key in structSort(arguments.metadata)){
                cs &= "#key#:#metadata[key]#\n";                
            }
    }           
    cs &= "x-amz-metadata-directive:REPLACE\n/#arguments.bucket#/#arguments.objectKey#";
    var signature = createSignature(cs);
    var httpReq = new http();
        httpReq.setMethod("PUT");
        httpReq.setUrl("http://#arguments.bucket#.s3.amazonaws.com/#arguments.objectKey#" );
        httpReq.addParam(type="header", name="Date", value="#dateTimeString#");
        httpReq.addParam(type="header", name="Content-Type", value="img/png");
        httpReq.addParam(type="header", name="x-amz-copy-source", value="/#arguments.bucket#/#arguments.objectKey#");
        httpReq.addParam(type="header", name="x-amz-metadata-directive", value="REPLACE");
        httpReq.addParam(type="header", name="Authorization", value="AWS #variables.accessKeyId#:#signature#");
        if(isdefined("arguments.metadata")){
            for(var i in arguments.metadata){
                httpReq.addParam(type="header", name="#i#", value="#arguments.metadata[i]#");
            }
        }
        var result = httpReq.send().getPrefix(); writedump(result); 
}
```